# NodeJs Server set on port XXXX, relative path GET domain:XXXX/path instead of domain/path

Tags: node.js, express, relative-path

I'm setting up a server on port XXXX which contains multiple route rendering ejs.
In these ejs files I try to access pictures with relative path (basically "../public/images/images.png") but it says that i'm trying to access domain:port/path instead of domain/path.

Here's the architecture of my server folder:

```
backend/
- node_modules/

- views/
-- home.ejs

- public/
-- images/
---images.png
```

```
const app = express()

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home');
});
```

[...]

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);

httpServer.listen(4000);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

File is missing because it's searched at domain:port/path (../public/images/images.png from views/home.ejs)

while I would like to search at domain/path

Comment: You should not use relative path from views instead use /images/xxxx.png because "/public" has already been defined as path for static files. 

And views folder cannot access other folder via relative path because that means it will be able to access the server files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using absolute path instead relative path

```
change 
../public/images/images.png
to
/images/images.png           // because you have added line
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); 
which directly refer to public folder for any of the static files.`
```

Comment: Since you have added app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); Directly you can refer /images/image.png instead of /public/images/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer mentioned by me in the comment is more correct than that has been answered here. I'll elaborate further so that you'd have a clear understanding of path binding.

This is supposedly your file structure:

```
backend/
- node_modules/

- views/
-- home.ejs

- public/
-- images/
---images.png

-app.js (I supposed it must be here)
```

**Express** does not let developers to access files from views folder to access anything from other folders other than inside the views folder only.

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

It's because of the above piece of code. If for instance say relative path could be used in a page say **Home.ejs** and was rendered then an attacker could easily replace an image path or any other path from

**"../public/images/images.png"** to **"../app.js"**. This simple hack would render out all your server javascript code including classified keys if defined to the attacker.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Anything in **public folder** can be used in the views folder without any root path declaration. We can join multiple or specific path for different styles and scripts or images in express.

> So you should always be careful what static path to include and what
>   to put inside of them.